# Java Curator/ZooKeeper client hanging indefinitely when ZooKeeper is not available on some executions

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

While testing Curator service discovery start multiple times, on some executions where ZooKeeper server is not available while
starting, it got waiting and hanging indefinitely, with thread dump stack trace which can be seen
below.
Example scenario is starting when ZooKeeper server is not available, and then ZooKeeper is available - but the Java thread remain hanging.
This is also reproduced with Curator unit test server: org.apache.curator.test.TestingServer.

ZooKeeper version is 3.6.

As this is not reproduced consistently, it seems like a race condition from Curator/ZooKeeper client.

```
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn.submitRequest(ClientCnxn.java:1561)
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn.submitRequest(ClientCnxn.java:1533)
org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:1834)
org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$16.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1131)
org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl$16.call(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1113)
org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:93)
org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:1110)
org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.protectedPathInForeground(CreateBuilderImpl.java:593)
org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:583)
org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CreateBuilderImpl.forPath(CreateBuilderImpl.java:48)
org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.internalRegisterService(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:237)
org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.reRegisterServices(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:456)
org.apache.curator.x.discovery.details.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.start(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:135)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
Solved with Curator 5.2.0 by using ZOOKEEPER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT:

```
ZKClientConfig zkClientConfig = new ZKClientConfig();
zkClientConfig.setProperty(ZKClientConfig.ZOOKEEPER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, zookeeperRequestTimeout);
client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkConnectString, 60000, 30000, retryPolicy, zkClientConfig);
```

- As a work-around solution prior to Curator 5.2.0,, initialization is executed in a separate thread in a pool in order to be able to stop it by interrupt if it hangs.